# Add javascript into WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am developing an application where in 1 part I want to add javascript into WebView.. But am not getting how to do it in an appropriate way.. Can anyone pls guide me into this?????

I am doing it like:

```
      wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

        wb.loadUrl("javascript:<script " ></script> ");
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing it through the *javascript:* protocol?

Comment: atleast show wat have you done so far

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was very simple..also without using any javascriptInterface..In my code, Instead writing:

```
 wb.loadUrl("javascript:<script>   </script>");
```

use,

```
  wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<script>   </script>","text/html","utf-8",null);
```

and its working now :)

Comment: But I want to add javascript file. how can I add it?

Comment: I tried [this](https://hastebin.com/icawevuwow.cpp) as per your suggestion, but not working at all, getting blank screen :(

Comment: Does this add the scripts to the webview?

Answer (score 0):

Look at these nice tutorials about **how to implements javascript in webview** in android..

I think its provides you all the information what you needed..

[Android WebView](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-webview.html)

[Android WebView, Javascript and CSS](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html)

**EDIT:** Further if your implemented code having any exception or not working then please post that code and exception then here we can help you..

Comment: My code runs instantly when I add it to webview. How can I just add a function which can be latter called from html??....for example I want to add a function which will be called when user will fill recaptcha with same name I used in data-callback of recaptcha