# Inject Javascript to website after ran script in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I want to add my javascript to the remote website.

I tried to use the method **onPageFinished** but it only get the website before the script run. The website has to get all data from server and I have to wait until it finished so I can add js to the generated element.

All elements I want to use have to wait until the script generate them

How can I know when the website has fully rendered? (ran all scripts and has all generated html)

**EDIT**

I can get the generated html but it can't help anything ( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview/4892013#4892013) )

I also tried many solutions but they didn't work ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url/5172952#5172952) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533187/add-javascript-into-webview))

**Here my sample code**

```
webPreviewDocument.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override  
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    webPreviewDocument.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Example');"); // just example
}
});
WebSettings webSettings = webPreviewDocument.getSettings();
webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webPreviewDocument.loadUrl(mMaterialPreview.getPreviewUrl());
```

[image: When the page is loading]

when onPageFinished called, the page is loading preview content, I have to wait few seconds and then to all the content loaded. I also tried to use *sleep* and *wait* for both js and java but it doesn't work

Comment: So if I understand you you want to run your JS file on a website you don't own?

Comment: yes, I want to do that, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your JS file:

```
var init = function () {
    //here you write your functions that need to be excuted by example:
    $('.checkbox').on('change', checkCheckbox);
};
$(document).ready(init());
```

The function init() can only be excuted when your document has loaded. 
This function is also written in Jquery. I don't know if you use that or know that. If you have any more questions just ask

Comment: I have tried that but it won't work. Because in Android, when I load a page, it always call onPageReturn immediately although the page have to load the preview content. 
For example: when you click to open an image in Google Photo, it have to load the preview content for few seconds before show it up.

Comment: Can you show me your android code? Also can you show me how you load that content?