# Selenium WebDriver inside WebView

Tags: android, webview, appium

I need to load a web application inside WebView and need to click on a certain button / or perform UI automation,

Is it possible to do that?

It is part of the android application, not testing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand using Selenium, but instead use Javascript events or JQuery.
For example you can add javascript to a webview.
[Add javascript into WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533187/add-javascript-into-webview)

And then you can use JQuery user interface like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#button-id").click();
});
```